# Simple JavaScript counter function

Tags: javascript, counter

I would like to make a counter function, and precise a variable for the starting time and the place to be displayed.

So if I would like to have many counter per page, I can easily manage it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            // set time and place (where to display the counter)
            function countDown(time, place){

                if(time > 0){
                    time--;    
                    setInterval(function(){countDown(time,place)}, 1000);
                } // end if

                if(time == 0)
                {
                    window.clearInterval(time);
                }
            } // end function

                     $('.click').click(function(){
                        countDown(30, '#counter');                              

                     });

}); // end DOM

   </script>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="click">clickme</div>
    <br />

    <div id="counter">30</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Did you forget to ask your question?

Comment: Note that *setInterval* does not run at exactly the specified interval, so the above will not run at exactly 1 second intervals so simply decrementing the value on each call will not accurately reflect the number of elapsed seconds. The function also calls itself on each run so after about 30 seconds you will have 30 timers running.

Comment: Also, *clearInterval* expects to be passed the value returned from the call to *setInterval*, not `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>


                var myVar;
var clickcount=0;

function countDown (time, place) {
        if (time > 0) {

        $(place).html(time);
        time--;
        myVar=setTimeout(function () { countDown(time, place); }, 1000);
  }
}

function startreset(time,place){
        clickcount++;
        if(clickcount % 2 === 0){
             clearTimeout(myVar);              
        } else {
            countDown(time,place);
        }

    }

$('.click').click(function(){
        startreset(30, '#counter');                              
        });



       </script>
    </head>




 <body>
        <div class="click" onClick="javascript:countDown(30,'#counter');">clickme</div>
        <br />

        <div id="counter">30</div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of you guys, I noticed something, if I click on "click me" the counter started, and if I click again, another counter started,is there a way to reset it, in both ways:

1- Once clicked again reset to 0,
2- Pause it.

If anybody can explain to me both situations

Thanks guys

Comment: Keep a global variable to keep track if it is has been pressed. It can be count=0; Every time you press call a function that increase count. Based count%2=0/1, you do something. Please upvote my response if you think it was helpful.

Comment: I've tested this one, just to check whether I've got ur idea, but it seems something hanging there: function clearTimer(ident){ ident++; if(ident % 2 == 0){ alert(0); } else { alert(1); } } $('.click').click(function(){ countDown(30, '#counter'); clearTimer(1); });

Comment: I have updated the javascript. It stops when you click twice and restart when you click again.

Comment: done dude, thanks man, I changed the code slightly, but the idea still remain the same: http://jsfiddle.net/aburayane/wsnXY/

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are likely having is that you are calling setInterval multiple times. setInterval does more than just wait the *x* milliseconds you tell it to and then call your method, it *continues* to call your method every subsequent *x* milliseconds. So, when you call countDown the first time, an interval is set for your function. That interval expires and countDown is called again. All fine so far, but now the second call to countDown establishes *ANOTHER* setInterval. The program will wait your *x* milliseconds to call countDown from the second setInterval, but it will call it from the first setInterval sooner.

...In other words, you shouldn't be repeatedly calling setInterval. What you want is setTimeout, which waits the specified amount of time and then calls the specified method *once*.

```
function countDown (time, place) {
  if (time > 0) {
    time--;
    $(place).html(time);
    setTimeout(function () { countDown(time, place); }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're not feeling recursive today:

```
function countDown (time, place) {
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (time > 0) {
      time--;
      $(place).html(time);
    } else {
      window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

which leverages setInterval, BUT ONLY ONCE.

JSFiddle provided: http://jsfiddle.net/LKvBR/

Comment: I've tested this one, just to check whether I've got ur idea, but it seems something hanging there:

[code]   
    function clearTimer(ident){
        ident++;
        if(ident % 2 == 0){
            alert(0);
        } else {
            alert(1);
        }
        
    }    
    
    $('.click').click(function(){
        countDown(30, '#counter');                              
        clearTimer(1);  
        });
[/code]